# how to get size of width and height in pixels of the selection area from the marquee tool in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, marquee, psd

I have photoshop cc, and trying to find out the width/height in pixels of the rectangular area made from the marquee tool.

```
How do i get the width/height in pixels of the rectangular area from the marguee tool in photoshop?
```

Comment: thanks a bunch man, web programmers have to deal with this all-the-time im sure.  please answer and ill check it off.

Comment: Not really a programming question! Press `F8` or go to the menu across the top of Photoshop and click `Window`->`Info`